# Evaluate the limit of the Appell F1 function.

Tags: calculus, limits, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in the following 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xF_1(1/2;n+1/2,-1/2;3/2;-x^2,-c x^2), $$ where $0<n<1/2$ and $c>0$. $F_1$ is the [Appell series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series). Any idea on how to obtain the limit.

Comment: The expression diverges.

Comment: @Lucian I think the expression would converge if the $x$ out front was removed. Perhaps that is what the OP intended?

Comment: @DavidH: Yeah... Sure it does... It converges to $0...$ Which is probably why he tried to multiply with *x* in the first place, so that the two tendencies might cancel each other off. I think what he meant, though, is to multiply with $\sqrt x.$

Comment: @DavidH: Actually, make that $x^{2n}.$ Also, for $c=1,$ it seems to converge to $\dfrac1{1-2n}$